# Guess schema: guess date pattern from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, talend

Using the *guess schema* function in Talend Open Studio for ESB, the software tries to map the fields values to the according Java types, which works most of the times.

When it comes to date fields (DATE or DATETIME), the TOS always uses "dd-MM-yyyy" as date pattern, which is wrong. As a result, I have to change the pattern manually for every (new) connection which is extremly time consuming.
If I click on *guess schema* "accidentally", the manually specified date pattern is overwritten again.

Is there a way to either make the guess schema function more intelligent or at least to specify my own default date pattern?

Answer (score 3):

Presently (version 6.3 of TOS), there is no way to do this.  However, Talend is aware of the issue and there is a new feature request that has been open for some time now.  See link below.

https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TUP-16975